# Why can't increase Connect Timeout?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

This is my setting:

```
$DBH = new PDO(
        "pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", 
        $username, 
        $password,
        array(
            PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 60,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        )
    );
```

It is time out after 20s.
But If i set  `PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 5`, It will time out after 5s.

Why can't increase Connect Timeout?
I using xampp 3.2.2, Database Postgresql 9.2
I test at local, not exist Anti Virus.

Comment: What error do you get? May be it is a server that is closing connction? Could you check in server logs and settings?

Comment: You should tell us more about your infrastructure it could be a server setting, it could be a proxy timeout (I saw load balancer timeout before and it took me time to figure it out) it could be anything that can timeout a connection in general!

Answer (score 9):

`PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT` and the `default_socket_timeout` INI setting are the only values you can change from PHP, but a TCP connection can be affected by a lot of factors.

On the client side, a firewall or the OS itself may also apply timeout limits.
In transit, any of the intermediate peers (your router, ISPs) can also drop connections based on various rules.

But most importantly (i.e. more likely in your case), the connection involves two parties and the PostgreSQL server also has its own timeout settings - `tcp_keepalives_idle`, `tcp_keepalives_interval`, `tcp_keepalives_count` and `authentication_timeout`.

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html

Exactly what affects you is impossible to guess, and you'd possibly need to change more than one setting. Check for each of the above that you can.

Answer (score 3):

execute `PDO::errorInfo` after the block if you want to find out why its timeouting

http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.errorinfo.php

and the timeout ist maybe from the other side why should the script waiting 60 sec when the db response timeout after 20 sec.

Answer (score 1):

use `ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 60);` before connect

Comment: have other setting?

Answer (score 1):

Just put

```
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 50);
before your PDO() connect string.
```

Comment: i had try but it is not working and  php.ini setting default_socket_timeout=60